# Symfony - Swiftmailer spool send an email several times

Tags: php, symfony, cron, swiftmailer, spool

I have a CRON Job which create emails to send in database.
It creates abouts 3000 unique emails to send.

Then I have a CRON job configured like this :

```
* * * * * php bin/console swiftmailer:spool:send --message-limit=200 --env=prod --no-debug
```

So the second CRON job try to send 200 emails each minute.
When I look :

```
ps aux | grep php
```

It shows multiple simultaneous processes swiftmailer:spool:send.

These simultaneous calls causes the multiple sending of the same email.
So today, one user will receive multiple same emails even if I have only one entry in my database.

Has someone already had this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: what happens if the first cron call doesn't complete in a minute?

Comment: after the messages are send you set a flag in the db so the other cron process does not send the same message again?

Comment: @madalinivascu : Your first comment remember me the option --time-limit. Maybe a --time-limit=55 could fix my issue.

Comment: @madalinivascu: I don't manage the flag in db, swiftmailer:spool:send manage him itself. It change its mail.status to 1 (pending_send) to 3 (sent).

Comment: you need to increase the time between calls so all mails are send and the flags updated, right now if the job takes longer than 1 min then the flags are not set for some of the emails so your server send them again believing that  the email aren't send

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use more than one `swiftmailer:spool:send` process to speed up sending emails then I think you should not use `spool` at all.
But you can rather use separate message queue system like RabbitMQ which deals with cases not to consume same message twice. Read more here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/18-async.html#going-async-for-real